# Zapier Scripting: Catch error and rewrite response

Tags: zapier

The app I'm integrating returns a 400 bad request when the search doesn't find a match which Zapier sees as an error.

How can I catch the error and return a [] to tell Zapier there is no match?

Here's the existing post_search code of got:

```
    match_person_email_post_search: function(bundle) {
        console.log(bundle.response.content);
        var res = JSON.parse(bundle.response.content);
        var data;

        if(res.person!==null)
        {
           data = [ res.person ];
        }
        else
        { data = []; }

        return data;
    },
```

I should probably mention I'm a rookie at this scripting!

Thanks!

Comment: Please consider including code so that we can better understand your problem.  As of right now I don't know what you're connecting, and what language/tools you're using.

Comment: If you're integrating the app, can't you adjust the search output if a search match is not found (and have it just return `[]`)?

Comment: @mam8cc post updated with existing Zapier code.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the search API result returns something, you should be able to capture that using Zapier scripting. Assuming your Zapier search key is `contact_data`, here is how the function would look:

```
var Zap = {
    search_contact_post_search: function(bundle) {
        return bundle.response.content;
    }
};
```

So you can check (within that function) if the data is empty or containing something other than search data, and just return an empty array:

```
var Zap = {
    search_contact_post_search: function(bundle) {
        var response_content = JSON.parse(bundle.response.content);
        if (!response_content.some_field) {
            return [];
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, really appreciate the response! I've updated my post to include the existing pre_search code (which I did not write – I'm a beginner with this scripting stuff). Just reading over it now, it seems that this code should already do the trick but it doesn't.

Comment: What does that function return now? Can you share what `res` looks like?

Comment: Sorry Matt, I'm not sure what `res` is at all. I've spoke to Zapier support and they've given me this:

`match_person_email_post_search: function(bundle){
  if(bundle.response.status_code == 400){
    return [];
  }

  // the rest of your processing done here
}
`
which I did (https://www.dropbox.com/s/2q3jzuag5s3znx7/nb_zapier%20app_issue400-2.png?dl=0) but I think I have the syntax wrong because it doesn't work. Thanks for the patience with my lack of understanding so far!